# Spring Cloud Stream function with Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to test the consumer of my event producer using StubTrigger.

Here is my contract:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    label "sendUserMessage"
    input {
        triggeredBy("sendUserMessageTriggered()")
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo"users-out-0"
        body '''{ "email": "existing-user@email.com", "location": [10.0, 20.5], "area": 3.5 }'''
    }
}
```

the yml from the producer:

```
spring:
  profiles: "local"
  cloud:
    stream:
      source: users
      bindings:
        users-out-0.destination: users
    config:
      enabled: false
      discovery.enabled: false
    discovery:
      enabled: false
```

Here is the consumer bean definition:

```
package br.com.marco.cadeacerva.notification.infra.config;

import br.com.marco.cadeacerva.notification.domain.UsersEventConsumer;
import br.com.marco.cadeacerva.notification.endpoints.dto.UserDTO;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FunctionsConfig {

    private final UsersEventConsumer usersEventConsumer;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<UserDTO> users() {
        return (u) -> {
            log.info("Received user on users function: {}", u.toString());
            usersEventConsumer.consume(u);
        };
    }
}
```

Here is my consumer test:

```
package br.com.marco.cadeacerva.notification.infra.config;

import br.com.marco.cadeacerva.notification.domain.UsersEventConsumer;
import br.com.marco.cadeacerva.notification.endpoints.dto.UserDTO;
import br.com.marco.cadeacerva.testcommons.utils.annotation.IntegrationTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubTrigger;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.AutoConfigureStubRunner;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@IntegrationTest
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL,
        ids = "br.com.marco.cadeacerva:users:+:stubs:8090")
public class FunctionsConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    StubTrigger trigger;

    @MockBean
    UsersEventConsumer consumer;

    @Test
    public void shouldConsumeUsersEvents() {
        trigger.trigger("sendUserMessage");
        verify(consumer).consume(any(UserDTO.class));
    }
}
```

And the consumer yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: "integration-tests"
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        users-in-0:
          destination: users
          group: users
    config:
      enabled: false
      discovery.enabled: false
    discovery:
      enabled: false

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

When I run the test it fails because of:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'users-out-0' available

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamFromBinderMappingMessageSender.send(StreamFromBinderMappingMessageSender.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamFromBinderMappingMessageSender.send(StreamFromBinderMappingMessageSender.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.send(StreamStubMessages.java:44)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.LazyMessageVerifier.send(StubRunnerConfiguration.java:212)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.sendMessage(StubRunnerExecutor.java:260)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.triggerForDsls(StubRunnerExecutor.java:215)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.trigger(StubRunnerExecutor.java:200)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunner.trigger(StubRunner.java:163)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner.trigger(BatchStubRunner.java:136)
    at br.com.marco.cadeacerva.notification.infra.config.FunctionsConfigTest.shouldConsumeUsersEvents(FunctionsConfigTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I even tried to define the same source configuration from my producer, on the consumer, but got the same exception. Don't know what I'm supposed to do in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example of the new Stream API and Spring Cloud Contract on the consumer side: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/3.0.x/consumer/src/test/java/com/example/BeerVerificationListenerTest.java Remember to ensure that you have the stream test dependency on the classpath

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

As for your code, your `sentTo` should point to `users` not `users-out-0`.

Let me copy paste what's there in the code.

Consumer side listener

```
package com.example;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * @author Marcin Grzejszczak
 */
@Component("input")
class BeerVerificationListener implements Consumer<BeerVerificationListener.Verification> {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BeerVerificationListener.class);

    AtomicInteger eligibleCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger notEligibleCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public void accept(Verification verification) {
        log.info("Received new verification");
        //remove::start[]
        //tag::listener[]
        if (verification.eligible) {
            this.eligibleCounter.incrementAndGet();
        } else {
            this.notEligibleCounter.incrementAndGet();
        }
        //end::listener[]
        //remove::end[]
    }

    public static class Verification {
        public boolean eligible;
    }
}
```

Consumer side setup

```
spring:
  application.name: beer-api-consumer
  # remove::start[]
  cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.destination: verifications
  # remove::end[]
server.port: ${PORT:8081}
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud: debug
```

Producer side code

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 * @author Marcin Grzejszczak
 */
@Service
public class AgeCheckingPersonCheckingService implements PersonCheckingService {

    private final StreamBridge source;

    public AgeCheckingPersonCheckingService(StreamBridge source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean shouldGetBeer(PersonToCheck personToCheck) {
        //remove::start[]
        //tag::impl[]
        boolean shouldGetBeer = personToCheck.age >= 20;
        this.source.send("output-out-0", new Verification(shouldGetBeer));
        return shouldGetBeer;
        //end::impl[]
        //remove::end[return]
    }

    public static class Verification {
        boolean eligible;

        public Verification(boolean eligible) {
            this.eligible = eligible;
        }

        public Verification() {
        }

        public boolean isEligible() {
            return this.eligible;
        }

        public void setEligible(boolean eligible) {
            this.eligible = eligible;
        }
    }
}
```

Producer side setup

```
spring:
    application.name: beer-api-producer
    cloud.function.definition: output
    cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0:
        # remove::start[]
        destination: verifications
        # remove::end[]
server.port: ${PORT:8080}
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud: debug
```

Contract definition

````
package contracts.beer.messaging

import com.example.ProducerUtils
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract 

Contract.make {
    description("""
Sends a positive verification message when person is eligible to get the beer
```
given:
    client is old enough
when:
    he applies for a beer
then:
    we'll send a message with a positive verification
```
""")
    // Label by means of which the output message can be triggered
    label 'accepted_verification'
    // input to the contract
    input {
        // the contract will be triggered by a method
        triggeredBy('clientIsOldEnough()')
    }
    // output message of the contract
    outputMessage {
        // destination to which the output message will be sent
        sentTo 'verifications'
        // the body of the output message
        body(
            eligible: true
        )
        headers {
            messagingContentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
````

Comment: Had some misconfiguration on my integration-tests producer yml too, but the sentTo "users" was really the problem...Thanks!